# Laravel - Combine multiple queries as one and also include GroupBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have written different queries that function for different things. I want to combine them as one (Sales for: Today, Current Week, Current Week, Current Month, Current Year and Overall Sales) and Group By a field called store.

```
            $currentYear = date('y');
        $currentyearbilling = DB::table("billings")
               ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
               ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?',$currentYear)
               ->get();

        $currentMonth = date('m');
        $currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
               ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
               ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',$currentMonth)
               ->get();

        $currentWeek = date('w');
        $currentweekbilling = DB::table("billings")
               ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
               ->whereRaw('WEEK(created_at) = ?',$currentWeek)
               ->get();

        $currentDay = date('d');
        $currentdaybilling = DB::table("billings")
               ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
               ->whereRaw('(created_at) = ?',$currentDay)
               ->get();
```

> Group By store.

The table name is called billings.  I still want to follow this format

> DB::table("billings")
>   How do I achieve this?

[image: syntax error]

**Error:**

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$currentYear = date('y');
$currentMonth = date('m');
$currentWeek = date('w');
$currentDay = date('d');

$currentyearbilling = DB::table("billings")
       ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
       ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?',$currentYear)
       ->orWhereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',$currentMonth)
       ->orWhereRaw('WEEK(created_at) = ?',$currentWeek)
       ->orWhereRaw('(created_at) = ?',$currentDay)
       ->groupBy('store')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have a table `billings` like this:

```
| column     | type       |
|------------|------------|
| id         | int        |
| store      | varchar    |
| amount     | int        |
| created_at | timestamps |
| updated_at | timestamps |
```

I will get amount of every store in `current_day`, `current_month`, `current_week`, `current_year`, and `overall` by using sub query like this:

```
select 
  store,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) from billings as child where child.store = parent.store and DAY(created_at) = ? and MONTH(created_at) = ? and YEAR(created_at) = ?) as current_day,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) from billings as child where child.store = parent.store and WEEK(created_at) = ?) as current_week,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) from billings as child where child.store = parent.store and MONTH(created_at) = ? and YEAR(created_at) = ?) as current_month,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) from billings as child where child.store = parent.store and YEAR(created_at) = ?) as current_year,
  SUM(amount) as overall,
  COUNT(id) as total_rows

from billings as parent

group by store
```

And with `Eloquent`, it would be just something like this:

```
$childQuery = \DB::table(\DB::raw('billings as child'))
    ->select(\DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amount'))
    ->whereRaw('child.store = parent.store');

$currentDayQuery = (clone $childQuery)->whereDay('created_at', now()->day)->whereMonth('created_at', now()->month)->whereYear('created_at', now()->year);
$currentWeekQuery = (clone $childQuery)->where(\DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'), now()->weekOfYear);
$currentMonthQuery = (clone $childQuery)->whereMonth('created_at', now()->month);
$currentYearQuery = (clone $childQuery)->whereYear('created_at', now()->year);

$rows = \DB::table(\DB::raw('billings as parent'))
    ->select([
        'store',
        \DB::raw('(' . $currentDayQuery->toSql() . ') as current_day'),
        \DB::raw('(' . $currentWeekQuery->toSql() . ') as current_week'),
        \DB::raw('(' . $currentMonthQuery->toSql() . ') as current_month'),
        \DB::raw('(' . $currentYearQuery->toSql() . ') as current_year'),
        \DB::raw('SUM(amount) as overall'),
        \DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total_rows')
    ])
    ->mergeBindings($currentDayQuery)
    ->mergeBindings($currentWeekQuery)
    ->mergeBindings($currentMonthQuery)
    ->mergeBindings($currentYearQuery)
    ->groupBy('store')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I up[dated my code at the point I got an error.  I got this error.      Syntax error
 unexpected: ->
 after: )
 expected: instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=, >=, <=>, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.', ], ), :, ??
----                          See it in the diagram

Comment: Can you be clear what error you got. Because its said it was a syntax error.

Comment: See the updated code for the error. It underlines some code as red. Then when I placed the cursor on it, I got this:         Syntax error unexpected: -> after: ) expected: instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=, >=, <=>, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.', ], ), :, ?? ---- See it in the diagram